# cassandra - SELECT result as WHERE condition

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

i want to use the result of select query as input of another queries condition like this:

```
DELETE FROM message_user WHERE id = 8a81de70-1991-11e9-a38f-9e0aa7c9f25f and group = e5b04c50-1982-11e9-abf3-b17ecbb80329 and receiver in (SELECT member FROM chat_group_member WHERE id = e5b04c50-1982-11e9-abf3-b17ecbb80329)
```

Comment: Cassandra Doesn't support this kind of queries... Handle it in your application

Comment: @undefined_variable are you sure? i don't think it have any conflicts with Cassandra Data Model. all parts of query work well as alone. but together not!

Comment: @undefined_variable is correct. Cassandra is a NoSQL database and does not support queries with multiple tables. This means no joins, no `IN`/`EXISTS` clauses, no subqueries. Handle that in your application.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Cassandra supports IN clauses.

Comment: @sadegh Does not support `IN` with queries. Should've been more clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is distributed database, Nested queries are type of joins. In Cassandra Data might be stored on multiple host. In order to make joint large data might need to be downloaded on single node.  This might cause performance issues as all nodes are on commodity hardware (peer to peer). Hence I think its not supported.